# Reading XML In Flash From An ASPX Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, flash, actionscript-3

I have created an aspx page which dynamicaly creates an xml string and posts it back to the client.

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        var flashAssets = Asset.GetScrollingFlashAssets();

        var xmlResponse = new StringBuilder(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" ?><assets>");
        flashAssets.ForEach(asset => xmlResponse.Append(@"<asset>handlers/ImageHandler.ashx?liAssetID=" + asset.AssetID + "</asset>"));
        xmlResponse.Append("</assets>");
        Response.Write(xmlResponse.ToString());
    }
```

It creates valid XML and when I save this code to a static .xml file the flash can read it fine, though when it tried to read it from the ASPX it fails with "1090 XML parser failure: element is malformed".

I do not have http compression on.

Flash code.

```
//---------loading the external xml file-------
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("../xml/CaseStudyFlashAssets.aspx");
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var myXML:XML = new XML();
var xmlList:XMLList;
myXML.ignoreWhitespace = true;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,fileLoaded);
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what does your fileLoaded function look like?

Comment: Your flash code doesn't show what it's actually doing with the response.  You're creating an XML object, but not doing anything with it.  Can you show where you actually handle the data you get back?  That's probably where the error is.

Comment: oh good point - your var myXML:XML = new XML(); line isn't really doing much.

It's also XML.ignoreWhitespace - it's a static property.

Comment: There's a fairly similar question (same error) posted a couple mins before this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811850/as3-retrieving-xml-from-aspx-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like when flash calls the aspx page it gets a different response than you're expecting, try using this fileLoaded function:

```
public function fileLoaded(event:Event):void{
     trace('urlLoader.data is ' + urlLoader.data);
     try{
          var xmlData:XML = XML(urlLoader.data);
     } catch (e:Error) {
          trace('Error creating XML: ' + e);
     }
}
```

which should hopefully give you some more info about whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
"<![CDATA[" and ends with "]]>"
```